# My Angular *ngif-condition doesn't work. It look okay, I cant find any error

Tags: angular-ng-if

If the `myFavorites.length` is 0, I want it shows the following message:

"There are no added movies in the Favorites."

Otherwise, the main content (`movieList`) will be shown.

```html
<div class="movie_container">
  <ng-template *ngIf="myFavorites.length === 0; else moviesList">
    <p>There are no added movies in the favorites list.</p>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #moviesList>
    <div *ngFor="let movie of myFavorites" class="movie_container">
      <img
        class="poster"
        [src]="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/' + movie.backdrop_path"
        [alt]="movie.title"
      />
      <h3>{{ movie.title }}</h3>
      <button (click)="removeFromFavorites(movie.id)">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If it's that you're expecting "There are no added movies in the favorites list" to show and it's not, make sure the list is empty. You can check that via `{{ myFavorites.length }}` in the template. Also make sure that you aren't emptying the list via mutations and are instead doing it reassignment so change detection can see the change. Or do the "reassignment" via a subject and check it using `| async`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the first `ng-container` won't render regardless of what `myFavorites.length === 0` is: true, false, or "access property of undefined".

Answer (score 0):

This

```
  <ng-template *ngIf="myFavorites.length === 0; else moviesList">
```

should be another tag, not `ng-template`. Try a plain old `div` for starters, `ng-container` will also do.

(BTW, the actual `moviesList` - it's a list, therefore we have better semantic HTML for that: either `ul` or `ol`, with every movie a `li`).

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. It should have been in the normal div. Thanks!